# First Chern class coincides with degree of divisor without poincare duality or de rham cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, line-bundles, holomorphic-bundles

I know there are a lot of references (e.g. Griffiths-Harris page 141), but the issue is that these references always prove the proposition in arbitrary dimensions, using a somewhat contrived calculation involving Stoke's Theorem but I feel like there should be a much simpler explanation in the case of curves.

So let $X$ be a projective nonsingular curve over $\mathbb{C}$. We have the exponential sequence $$ 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X^*\rightarrow 0$$ which gives us a long exact sequence in cohomology, and the first Chern Class is given by $H^1(\mathcal{O}_X^*) \rightarrow H^2(\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$. Now a Cech 1-cocycle $\{g_{\alpha\beta}\}$ for a sufficiently fine cover of $X$ in $\mathcal{O}_X^*$ encodes the information of a line bundle, and based on what I have read the image of this in $H^2(\mathbb{Z})$ is given by $\{(\log g_{\alpha\beta} - \log g_{\alpha\gamma} + \log g_{\beta\gamma})/ 2\pi i \}$ where the discrepancies in the choice of logarithm give rise to the cohomology class. It seems to me that the poles and zero's of local sections used to define the $g_{\alpha\beta}$ should encode the "failure" to produce logarithms, but unfortunately I am lost as to where I should go from here. Any help, including an explanation about why this is doomed to fail will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Though not exactly "simpler", comparison between different ways to define the first Chern class is described in great details in proposition 4.4.12 and 4.4.13 in Huybrechts' complex geometry. The proofs work for all compact complex manifolds and rely on connections and a bit of Chern-Weil theory. 

I suppose that fundamentally this might not be so easy. $deg(D)$ seems to be more related to singular cohomology, meanwhile the exponential sheaf sequence description is based on sheaf/Cech cohomology. So relating these two requires some kind of knowledge how the two cohomology are isomorphic.